# Do we get push store data into database or save data then update store in @wordpress/data

Tags: wordpress, react-redux, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to integrate WordPress store for plugin. I have little confusion. Do we first update the store and retrieve store data to push it into database. Or is it the other way. I know it's really naive question, but I'm new to this. Thank you for your help and please be kind to me.

Comment: I have experience working with the Wordpress JS packages but I need to review the docs because I get the names mixed up.  The package which is used by the editor you would dispatch to immediately.  It stores the pending changes in the store and uses auto save and submit actions to push those changes to the API/database.  That’s for working with posts and custom post types as other entities like tags don’t support revisions.  If you’re editing a tag I would store the changes to local state and only push to the API on submit.  Are you working in the editor or on the front-end?

Comment: @LindaPaiste I'm working on editor. It involves custom post type with taxonomies, post_meta, feature image and all. Trying but smaller confusion as above as such.